# Query does not return output

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I'm writing a program where when user selects a certain choice using radio buttons,  then parameters and sql statements get assigned:

```
if(r1.isSelected())//SNo
    {
        cmd="SELECT * FROM CALLDETAILS WHERE SNo=?";
        parameter=tf1.getText();

    }
    else if(r2.isSelected())//Month-wise
    {
        cmd="SELECT SNO, DATE, COMPANY,STATUS FROM CALLDETAILS WHERE MONTH(DATE)=?";
        parameter=tf1.getText();
    }
    else if(r2.isSelected())//Username
    {
        cmd="SELECT * FROM CALLDETAILS WHERE ATTENDED_BY=?";
        parameter=tf1.getText();
    }
    else if(r3.isSelected())//Company
    {
       cmd="SELECT * FROM CALLDETAILS WHERE COMPANY=?";
        parameter=tf1.getText();
    }
    else//Status
    {
        cmd="SELECT * FROM CALLDETAILS WHERE Status=?";//Resolved. in process, pending
        parameter=tf1.getText();            
    }
```

When I run this:

```
try
    {

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tenderdetails?user=root&password=");
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ps=con.prepareCall(cmd);
        ps.setString(1,parameter);

        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();       

        while(rs.next())
        {
            int sno=rs.getInt(1);
            Timestamp dt=rs.getTimestamp(2);           
            System.out.println(sno+ "  "+dt);//HERE!
        }

        con.close();
        System.out.println("here too");
    }

    catch(SQLException se)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error: "+se.getMessage());
    }
```

There is no output of the statement marked HERE. Why is that?

Comment: Because your SQL statement did not return any hits...

Comment: It seems your query not returning any thing (while loop not executing at all).

Comment: Did you get an exception thrown?

Comment: But my database is returning values otherwise... in the mysql server.

Comment: No exceptions were returned.

Comment: check the `getConnection()` string

Comment: I tried assigning values instead of '?', still nothing. The variables are getting values assigned correctly

Comment: Great, thanks! The getConnection thing solved it! xD

Comment: Although, I basically just wrote the same thing again.

Comment: Well... No error message before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the `getConnection()` string and your Query/Prepared statement.

Since it doesn't return any results the problem is likely here.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that your statements aren't necessarily set to what you think;

```
else if(r2.isSelected())//Month-wise   // <-- r2
{
    cmd="SELECT SNO, DATE, COMPANY,STATUS FROM CALLDETAILS WHERE MONTH(DATE)=?";
    parameter=tf1.getText();
}
else if(r2.isSelected())//Username     // <-- r2 again...? Won't ever be hit.
```

Also, although most likely not your problem, `getInt(1)` and `getTimestamp(2)` seem a bit dangerous with `SELECT *`.

Comment: I intend to change the SELECT *. That was just to get the code running.